# Copy Conditional Formatting Between Workbooks

Tags: excel-2010, copy-paste, conditional-formatting

I have about 100 or so columns with multiple conditional formats applied to each column that I need to copy from one excel document to another. I've tried solutions from the Format Painter, to Paste Special, each failing to actually copy the conditional formats over. I hope I'm doing it wrong, as it would mean an easy fix for an otherwise, extremely long process (again).
Is there any way to copy conditional formats from one workbook to another? I don't need to worry about copying over equations or cell values, just the formats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Paste special > Formats` would carry over the conditional formatting.

Try copying (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and then paste special (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and select `Formats`

Comment: See, that's what I have found everywhere, and if I'm within the same excel document than it works perfectly. But when I move to a separate document and go into the paste special Formats options, these are what I get: [link](http://pasteboard.co/7KSiDIlSQ.png).

Comment: You are working in a separate **instance** of excel. Open excel once and then use the file>open dialog to open the two files you need to work with. You should then be able to paste formatting from one to the other. Which version of excel are you using?

Comment: Yep, that would do it. I had excel open in two separate windows for the dual monitor setup, versus the default merged one window. Wish you got back sooner though, as over the last 3 hours I just manually imported everything over.... Oh well, won't ever happen again, that's for sure.
And as the tag in the OP notes, this is Excel 2010.

Comment: Be careful.  When I do this the condition in the book pasted refers back to the book it was copied from

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the worksheet with the complex conditional formatting that you like, so you have a new copy with the desired behavior.  And then simply copy the new values you'd like from your new workbook that doesn't have conditional formatting yet and paste–special–values those numbers.  Or paste–special–value–formulas, as the desired case may be.